# Most efficient way to convert/flatten entire map to list (keys & values together , not separately)

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I need to convert following:

```
Map<Long,Map<String,String>> mapOfMaps
```

to

```
List<List<String>> listOflists
```

where keys of outer map (`mapOfMaps`) are redundant (for this operation). So basically , I can just use `mapOfMaps.values().stream()` to start with.

And for each map object e.g.:

> {"apple":"1","orange":"2"}

I need to convert it to a list :

> {"apple","1","orange","2"}

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Complete example:

> { 
>         "1L" : { "key1" : "value1" , "key2" : "value2" } ,
>         "2L" : { "key3" : "value3" , "key4" : "value4" } 
>      }

Expected:

> [[key1, value1, key2, value2], [key3, value3, key4, value4]]

Comment: It seems your target structure example does not match the type, the example ist just a List<String>, so what’s the expected outcome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
List<List<String>> listOflists =
    mapOfMaps.values()
             .stream()
             .map(m -> m.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .flatMap(e->Stream.of(e.getKey(),e.getValue()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For each inner `Map`, you stream over the `entrySet()`, and create a stream of all the keys and values, which you collect into a `List`.

For example, if you initialize the `Map` with:

```
Map<Long,Map<String,String>> mapOfMaps = new HashMap<>();
mapOfMaps.put(1L,new HashMap());
mapOfMaps.put(2L,new HashMap());
mapOfMaps.get(1L).put("key1","value1");
mapOfMaps.get(1L).put("key2","value2");
mapOfMaps.get(2L).put("key3","value3");
mapOfMaps.get(2L).put("key4","value4");
```

You'll get the following `List`:

```
[[key1, value1, key2, value2], [key3, value3, key4, value4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is my version of solution. You can iterate over entry and add values to desired list accordingly.

```
        List<List<String>> list = map.
                values()
                .stream()
                .map(value -> {
                    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : value.entrySet()) {
                        list1.add(entry.getKey());
                        list1.add(entry.getValue());
                    }
                    return list1;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Test Input:**

```
        Map<Long, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, String> submap1 = new HashMap<>();
        submap1.put("test", "test2");

        Map<String, String> submap2 = new HashMap<>();
        submap2.put("test6", "6");

        map.put(1l, submap1);
        map.put(2l, submap2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a  solution, which is a little less cool than nested lambdas, but a little more readable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a result list
    List<List<String>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

    // create some try-out values
    // a source map
    Map<Long,Map<String,String>> mapOfMaps = new HashMap<>();
    // some sub maps
    Map<String, String> subMapOne = new HashMap<>();
    subMapOne.put("One", "1");
    subMapOne.put("Two", "2");
    subMapOne.put("Three", "3");

    Map<String, String> subMapTwo = new HashMap<>();
    subMapTwo.put("Two", "2");

    Map<String, String> subMapThree = new HashMap<>();
    subMapThree.put("One", "1");
    subMapThree.put("Three", "3");

    mapOfMaps.put(1l, subMapOne);
    mapOfMaps.put(2l, subMapTwo);
    mapOfMaps.put(3L, subMapThree);

    // just nest two forEach-calls
    mapOfMaps.forEach((key, value) -> {
        // create a new list for each submap
        List<String> subList = new ArrayList<>();
        value.forEach((subKey, subValue) -> {
            // and add each entry of the submap to it
            subList.add(subKey);
            subList.add(subValue);
        });
        // finally add the list to the result list
        resultList.add(subList);
    });

    resultList.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The output is

```
[One, 1, Two, 2, Three, 3]
[Two, 2]
[One, 1, Three, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a third-party library the following will work using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
@Test
public void mapOfMapsToListOfLists()
{
    MutableMap<Long, MutableSortedMap<String, String>> map = Maps.mutable.with(
            1L, SortedMaps.mutable.with("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"),
            2L, SortedMaps.mutable.with("key3", "value3", "key4", "value4"));

    MutableList<MutableList<String>> listOfLists = map.valuesView()
            .collect(innerMap -> innerMap.keyValuesView()
                    .flatCollect(this::pairToList).toList())
            .toList();

    List<List<String>> expected = Lists.mutable.with(
            Lists.mutable.with("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"),
            Lists.mutable.with("key3", "value3", "key4", "value4"));
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, listOfLists);
}

public ImmutableList<String> pairToList(Pair<String, String> pair)
{
    return Lists.immutable.with(pair.getOne(), pair.getTwo());
}
```

I initialized the inner maps as `SortedMap`s in order to guarantee the order of the keys in the call to `Assert.assertEquals` in the test.  The interface types I used above are from Eclipse Collections and extend the JDK interface types (e.g. MutableMap extends Map, MutableList extends List), but you can also use JDK types with static utility as follows:

```
@Test
public void jdkMapOfMapsToListOfLists()
{
    Map<Long, Map<String, String>> map = Maps.mutable.with(
            1L, SortedMaps.mutable.with("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"),
            2L, SortedMaps.mutable.with("key3", "value3", "key4", "value4"));

    List<List<String>> listOfLists = MapIterate.collect(map,
            innerMap -> Iterate.flatCollect(
                    innerMap.entrySet(),
                    this::entryToList,
                    new ArrayList<>()));

    List<List<String>> expected = Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"),
            Arrays.asList("key3", "value3", "key4", "value4"));
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, listOfLists);
}

public List<String> entryToList(Map.Entry<String, String> entry)
{
    return Arrays.asList(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections